# webm / vp8 player for java

Tags: java, vp8, webm

does anyone know of a java library that plays vp8 or webm videos?

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) can play webm and vp8 videos since version 1.1.0, and there are Java bindings available for it. Have a look at:

- jVLC: http://wiki.videolan.org/Java_bindings
- VLCJ: http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/

I've used jVLC and it works, but it is not actively maintained anymore. VLCJ looks very good.

Comment: VLCJ is now the preferred Java VLC binding with the older JVLC now abandoned.

Answer (score 5):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/javavp8decoder/

it's beta but maybe it's a start.

Comment: Like I see this is just for webp images so far.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any native implementations (yet) but there are plugins for gstreamer and ffmpg , both have very good java-wrappers